# Manage to access in a loop function both the character and the variable associated with a letter/number of that character

Tags: r, string, loops

I'm trying to use a specific format of strings of years and month in a loop function, but I want to access a specific variable through the month of a string. Knowing that the variable has the number of that month : cycle1 refers to the cycle of 2013-01 for example.

```
    months <- c("2013-01", "2013-02", "2013-03")
    cycle1 <- 0
    cycle2 <- 0
    cycle3 <- 0

    for (k in months) 
{
    print(k)      # I need to use this "YYYY-mm" format
    #print(cycle1) # But what I also need to print is : Cycle1 Cycle2 Cycle3 Cycle4 etc.

    }
```

I'm aware there is a possibility by using the assign() function but I haven't figured out how to use it along a function that transforms for example 2013-06 into 6.
Thank you!

EDIT : As an output I want to print : "2013-01" cycle1 "2013-02" cycle2 "2013-03" cycle3 with the loop function.

Comment: What do you expect as your result?

Comment: @NelsonGon in this example I want to print : "2013-01" cycle1 "2013-02" cycle2 "2013-03" cycle3

Comment: Is this what you need: `cycles<-list(cycle1=cycle1,cycle2=cycle2,cycle3=cycle3);
paste0(months," ",names(cycles))`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure whether you want the names or the values of cycle1, cycle2, etc. Here are two possible answers:

```
library(stringr)
months <- c("2013-01", "2013-02", "2013-03")
cycle1 <- 0
cycle2 <- 0
cycle3 <- 0
cycle <- list(cycle1, cycle2, cycle3)
for (i in 1:length(months)) {
    print(months[i])
    print(cycle[[as.numeric(str_sub(months[i], 6, 7))]])
}
```

Which gives this result:

```
[1] "2013-01"
[1] 0
[1] "2013-02"
[1] 0
[1] "2013-03"
[1] 0
```

And this

```
library(stringr)
months <- c("2013-01", "2013-02", "2013-03")
cycle1 <- 0
cycle2 <- 0
cycle3 <- 0
cycle <- list(cycle1 = cycle1, cycle2 = cycle2, cycle3 = cycle3)
for (i in 1:length(months)) {
    print(months[i])
    print(names(cycle[as.numeric(str_sub(months[i], 6, 7))]))
}
```

Which gives this result

```
[1] "2013-01"
[1] "cycle1"
[1] "2013-02"
[1] "cycle2"
[1] "2013-03"
[1] "cycle3"
```

Comment: Thank you ! It was the second output that I was looking for !

Answer (score 0):

```
months <- c("2013-01", "2013-02", "2013-03")

lapply(1:length(months), function(x) assign(paste0("cycle", x), months[[x]], envir = globalenv()))
```

I guess this is what you want?